# How to create a analysis table for a logic propositions

Tags: logic, lexical-analysis

I have this is grammar:

```
F = F and F
F = F or F 
F = F => F
F = F <=> F
F = not F
F = (F)
D = a
```

but this grammar has an ambiguity, I have stripped the ambiguity like this:

```
F = F and A
F = A
A = F or B 
A = B
B = F => C
B = C
C = F <=> C
C = D
D = not F
D = (F)
D = a
```

its true or no ?

Comment: no 
not not a is possible ...

Comment: Ah, you are right. But it will parse `not a or b` as `not (a or b)`, which is a bit odd.

Comment: my grammer is true or not , for creat a table of analysis ?